# Why are many TCP open connections created on OS (Linux)?

Tags: java, linux, connection, tcp, asynchttpclient

I am using Apache AsychHttpClient with connection pool to send more than 1 mio requests and configured maxinum number of connection (200) and of connection per Host (100).

However there are many open TCP connections (about 30.000) on linux. Why? How can I control number of connection over Java on linux?